Cycles Combined Texture Bake doesn't match Cycles Render
Fairly experienced Blender user here with many bakes under my belt with textures that perfectly match combined render pass.
My problem is, my texture baked as a combined pass in cycles doesn't match in this case and I'm not sure why. See below:

I've checked, and the below aren't an issue:

Lights enabled for bakes, but not for viewport preview
Objects enabled for bakes, not for viewport, which might be casting shadows or obscuring lights
Resolution settings for cycles bakes
Disabling Optix / Denoise doesn't change that the result is wrong.

What I'm considering:

Whether this is a blender 3.6 issue. Going to check if this happens in blender 4.
Any other ideas?

Scene Layout (circled items are what I want in render+bake):

Bake and Sampling Settings:


I've tried tons of variations of this, see above bullets.

Material:


Does your mesh have a subdiv surface modifier ? Maybe it's only visible for rendering and not used for baking, or something like that ?

@Lutzi THIS WAS THE CULPRIT! How silly, many thanks
